# Postgresql Text Array get rows NOT LIKE certain value?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a simple table such as this one:

```
id_ | tags
---------------
0   | foo1, baz
1   | bar1, qux
```

The `id_` column is of type `SERIAL` and the `tags` column is of type `TEXT[]` (text array).

In order to search the `tags` column with the `LIKE` operator I use a combination of `unnest` and `DISTINCT ON` like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id_) *
FROM (
  SELECT unnest(tags) tag, *
  FROM Records
) x
WHERE
  (tag LIKE '%o%');
```

This works fine. The query returns row `0` like it should.

Now I'm trying to figure out a way to *invert* the query, so that it only returns rows that don't match the `LIKE` expression. I tried with this:

```
WHERE
  (tag NOT LIKE '%o%');
```

but it doesn't seem to work... My idea was that this query should return row `1` only, but it returns both rows.

I also tried with sub queries, for example like this one:

```
    WHERE
      (x.id_ NOT IN (SELECT id_ FROM Records WHERE tag like '%o%'));
```

But it still returns both rows.

Does anyone know how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ALL` to check, that all unnested tags are `NOT LIKE '%o%'` by using Postgres' ability to return Booleans for comparison expressions.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id_) *
       FROM records
       WHERE true = ALL (SELECT tag NOT LIKE '%o%'
                                FROM unnest(tags) tag);
```

If one tag is `LIKE '%o'`, `NOT LIKE '%o%'` will return `false` for that tag and no longer are all selected vales `true` what would be necessary for `true = ALL (...)` to be `true`.

BTW, you could also easily negate this using `ANY` and `LIKE` instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id_) *
       FROM records
       WHERE true = ANY (SELECT tag LIKE '%o%'
                                FROM unnest(tags) tag);
```

(or possibly other combinations of `true` or `false`, `= ALL` or `= ANY`, `(SELECT tag LIKE ...)` or `(SELECT tag NOT LIKE ...)`)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5763f/3)

Comment: You don't need the `true =` part. PG is good about Booleans, unlike SQL Server and Oracle.

Comment: @jpmc26: I do need it, as the `ALL` or `ANY` operator needs something to compare to. Just `WHERE ALL (...)` throws a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

`like` only has to match one tag.  `not like` has to match *all* of them.  Hence, aggregation:

```
SELECT id_
FROM (SELECT unnest(tags) tag, *
      FROM Records
     ) x
GROUP BY id_
HAVING SUM( (tag LIKE '%o%')::int) = 0;
```

Or use `bool_and()`:

```
HAVING bool_and( (tag LIKE '%o%')::int);
```

Comment: Why convert to `int` and use `SUM` instead of the dedicated `bool_and` and `bool_or` aggregate functions?

Comment: @jpmc26 . . . Good point.  It is a habit because I use a lot of different databases.